# Where did my unicoin purchases go?

Tags: feature-request, unicoins

I purchased some very nice things that took me a lot of clicking to earn the unicoins for, and now they're gone. I want my unicoins back with a full accounting of this. I am not a happy customer!

Also, what happened to my hats?

Comment: Yeah I actually want to re-enable that, I was busy most of the day and when I finally got back I wanted to purchase everything, only to see it was gone :(

Answer (score 9):

The very nice things are currently in limbo- that is, they are playing part of a huge limbo game.

This limbo game occurs with hats and unicoins and prizes, all day, on April 2nd, in Unicorntopia. Unfortunately, there are no accountant unicorns in Unicorntopia, so we can't provide you a receipt of what you have paid for with unicoins.

Please stay calm as we try to intercept this limbo game- we've tried talking to [BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) but he is too busy partying. We did get a snapshot of him dressed up, though:

[image]

We're sorry for the short delay- it's really hard to get anything done here, beacuse the snacks are good and the air smells nice.

Comment: Well I want something done.

Comment: Give me my unicorns back, please